# Indoor positioning system hardware

Tags: 3d, tracking, hardware, system-requirements

I'm a software developer, don't know much about the hardware specifications and don't know where to start. (Even not sure is that the right stackexchange I should ask this question.)

So, I want to know about (1) the cost and (2) document, link, etc. for the following specifications:

I want to make a project which I will put a chip (?) to a user and track that users 3D location with at least 10 cm accuracy, 10 times a sec, in a particular approximately 25x40 meters place and use that 3D location in my C, C++, Python, Java application. I read something about triangulation, and it makes sense. However that's all I know. I don't know any device that I can buy to do such...

Can you send me something to read?

Comment: Can the hardware be a mobile/cell phone?

Comment: No, I forgot to mention about that, sorry. Im searching for as possible as cheap hardware.

Comment: please define cheap? $2, $50, $100? Raspberry Pi's are technically cheap $25/$35 http://www.raspberrypi.org/faqs

Comment: This is overkill but can be done cheaply http://www.satsignal.eu/ntp/Raspberry-Pi-NTP.html

Comment: WiFiSLAM (recently purchased by Apple inc) 'Modern Innovations in Indoor Positioning' http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OGdvjvla1Tc

Comment: About the cost: probably there would be a client (chip on user) and server (device which is gonna calculate the locations) Cost for client: 70$ cost for server: 300$ most.